# Why it doesn't display POST value?

Tags: php

Why it doesn't display POST value?

Error: Notice: Undefined index: q[abc]
in line:  `echo $_POST['q[abc]'];`

Thanks!

```
<form method="POST" action="post.php" name="tq">

    <input type="hidden" name="q[id]" value="1035">


    <input type="radio" name="q[abc]" value="3001"></div>
    <div>A</div>

    <input type="radio" name="q[abc]" value="3002"></div>
    <div>B</div>

    <input type="radio" name="q[abc]" value="3003"></div>
    <div>C</div>

    <input type="submit" name="add" value="Next">


</form>


<?php
if (isset($_POST['add'])) {
    echo $_POST['q[abc]']; //error line
}
?>
```

Comment: 1st var_dump($_POST)... what does it give you?

Comment: remove the brackets from the input name so that it reads q_abc then it should work. I always try to refrain from putting special chars into input names. Obviously you need to ammend the post print out to reflect the change too.

Comment: array (size=2)
  'q' => 
    array (size=2)
      'id' => string '1035' (length=4)
      'abc' => string '3001' (length=4)
  'add' => string 'Next' (length=4)

Comment: I dont think `q[abc]' is a valid name for any html element. Is it ? Refer http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/types.html#type-name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `echo $_POST['q[abc]'];` you should try `echo $_POST['q']['abc'];`

Answer (score 1):

`name="q[abc]"` is the specific syntax to make PHP create an array, which you can then access like so:

```
echo $_POST['q']['abc'];
```

Answer (score 1):

You should do:

```
echo $_POST['q']['abc'];
```

If you have other issues like this in the future please use:

```
var_dump($_POST);
```

To see what a variable contains.

Answer (score 1):

when you put `name="q[abc]"` you make q an array, to see the value you must:

```
echo $_POST['q']['abc'];
```